# É possivel criar dicionarios usando laços de reptição?

Tags: python, lista, loop, for, dicionário

Queria saber, se consigo criar uma dicionário usando laços de repetição.
Mas não quero criar um dicionário dentro de uma lista [{ }].

exemplo:

```
from random import randint
jog = dict()
for n in range(1, 5):
   jog['Numb'] = randint(0, 6)
print(jog)
```

Comment: Sim, mas não pode haver chaves repetidas, neste caso 'Numb' vai ficar com o último valor atribuido

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível e o seu código já faz isso.

Porém, como comentado, pelo fato de você sempre atribuir à mesma chave no dicionário, você estará sempre sobrescrevendo o valor antigo. Desta forma, a sua saída sempre será algo como `{'Numb': 6}`, em que o valor 6, neste exemplo, foi definido aleatoriamente.

Se a ideia é armazenar todos os valores em chaves distintas, você poderia concatenar o valor de `n`, que é a sua variável de iteração, para gerar chaves únicas:

```
from random import randint
jog = dict()
for n in range(1, 5):
   jog[f'Numb-{n}'] = randint(0, 6)
print(jog)
```

Assim a saída seria algo como:

```
{'Numb-1': 1, 'Numb-2': 3, 'Numb-3': 1, 'Numb-4': 0}
```

Ainda, utilizando a sintaxe de *dict comprehension*, você pode simplificar em uma linha de código:

```
jog = {f'Numb-{n}': randint(0, 6) for n in range(1, 5)}
```

Produzindo um resultado equivalente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora entendi muito melhor.